# VMWare capacity planner and monitoring network packets/second

Tags: monitoring

My client requested that we provide him 'packets/second' statistics for all servers monitored using Capacity Planner. Does anybody knows if it is possible and how to do that?
I can get the bytes/second without trouble but not the packets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capacity Planner has a custom report template for Network Packets Per Second - You can find it under Reports - Custom Reports - New. This launches the Custom Reports Wizard and you'll find it in there. You can also add the Packets\sec counter to any custom report you want to build.